# Asignar Val a input text al seleccionar Select html con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo que toma la data de un webapi rest usando jQuery:

```
   const urlb = 'https://localhost:7123/clientes';

    $.getJSON(urlb, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            dropd.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.IdCliente).text(entry.codigoCliente));
        })
```

Necesito que apenas se seleccione un cliente del select se rellene los inputtext de nombre, direcion y telefono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El esquema del json es:

```
    [
     {
       "idCliente": 0,
       "codigoCliente": "string",
       "nombreCliente": "string",
       "direccionCliente": "string",
       "telefonoCliente": "string"
     }
    ]
```

he tomado el val por medio del entry pero no he recordado el manejo de este ya que llevo algo de tiempo que no realizaba esta acción

```
entry
: 
codigoCliente
: 
"28246"
direccionCliente
: 
"0 Dottie Way"
idCliente
: 
1
nombreCliente
: 
"Ame Hembery"
telefonoCliente
: 
"6890617"
```

EDICION
Lo que he intentando es...

```
$('#selCliente').change(function(){
    $("#txtNombreCliente").val(this.value);//"ACA Tomar el valor de lo cargado del api"
})
```

tambien asignando data attributes de [html5](https://johnresig.com/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)
al llamar la data hice algo asi:

```
dropd.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.IdCliente).text(entry.codigoCliente).dataName (entry.nombreCliente).dataAdrz(entry.direccionCliente).dataTel(entry.telefonoCliente));
```

Comment: Debes usar el evento `change` en el `select` para lanzar una función en javascript que te recalcule que datos se corresponden con el id de cliente seleccionado segun tu json, y rellenar los campos correspondientes con ellos. Inténtalo y pon dicho código en la pregunta para que sea válida, pues aún no lo has probado y de momento no tienes errores que solucionar.

Comment: @masterguru si tienes razón la publique ayer tarde en la noche ya la modifico